# can't get data-source in modal in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to get data-src (youtube link from database) value in my modal, but it's not fetching . my codes so far :

from controller :

```
foreach($ondemand_data as $row)
   {
    $ondemand_output .= '

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
                   <div class="aspire-video-content">
                       <div class="aspire-video-thumb">
                           <img src="../storage/webinar/'.$row->image.'" alt="" class="img- 
                     thumbnail">
                           <div class="aspire-video-thumb-content">
                               <button type="button" class="btn video-btn" data-toggle="modal" 
                                 data-src="'.$row->video_link.'" data-target="#myModal">
                                   <img src="../img/video/video-img.png" alt="">
                               </button>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="aspire-video-txt-content">
                           <div class="aspire-video-txt" style="height: 160px">
                               '.str_limit($row->description, 180).'
                           </div>
                           <input type="text" value="'.$row->video_link.'" class="" id="get- 
                          video-url">
                           <button type="button" class="btn video-btn aspire-video-btn" data- 
                          toggle="modal" data-src="'.$row->video_link.'" data- 
                    target="#myModal">
                               Watch Now
                           </button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div> 
           ';
   }
  }
```

and code from my script are (scripts are from the blade page):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     
        var $videoSrc;
        $('.video-btn').click(function() {
            $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
        });
        console.log($videoSrc);
         
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        
            $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "? 
         autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0" );
        })
       
        $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
            
            $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc);
        })
           
    });
</script>
```

Please ask me if you need more code for better analysis

Comment: $videoSrc = $(this).attr("data-src");

Comment: What do you get in you make a print_r($ondemand_data)

Comment: @JohnLobo,not works

Comment: @BernhardBeatus it gets url from database, but don't get at modal

Comment: $(document).click('.video-btn',function() {
            $videoSrc = $(this).attr("data-src");
        });

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/bqm2nLaf/7/

Youtube is not working in Stackoverflow

Replace

```html
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RydO8iGhwEY"
```

with

```php
src="' . $row->video_link . '"
```

then make

```php
foreach($ondemand_data as $row) {
    $unique = uniqid();
    .....
}
```

replace

```php
data-target="#exampleModal-' . $unique . '"
id="exampleModal-' . $unique . '"
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="aspire-video-txt">
  <p>Your Description</p>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</div>
<input type="text" value="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RydO8iGhwEY" class="" id="get-video-url">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Watch now
</button>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RydO8iGhwEY" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```